# Crystal Reports 13. Formula to extract part of string

Tags: string, crystal-reports, extract

I am using Crystal Reports 13.

I have field in my data that contains a string that includes various times.

Examples:
0010800;0011000;0011200;0011400;0011600;0011800;0011900
0010000;0010600;0011200;0011409;0011415;0011800
0010000;0010400;0010800;0011200;0011600;0012000
0010600;0011015;0011428;0011800;0012229

What is the best way to extract the four digits before the ";". 
For the first line I need to see something like this:

“08:00, 10:00, 12:00, 14:00, 16:00, 18:00 and 19:00”

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0):

```
Local Stringvar inString = {Table.FieldName};
Local Stringvar arr := Split(inString, ";");

For i := 1 To Count (arr)
(
    arr[i] := MID(arr[i],4,5) + ":" + MID(arr[i],6,7);
)
```

I believe the above should work, setting the variable `inString` to the value of your field containing your data. Splitting it into an array, with it being split on each `;`.

Then loop through that array, copy each entry back into place with just the last four characters and the `:` inserted in the middle of them. You're then free to do whatever you need to with the array.

Comment: Many thanks. The request was actually on behalf of a colleague so I will forward to him and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Cool, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Local stringVar i;
Local Stringvar inString = {Table.FieldName};
Local stringVar array arr := Split(inString, ";");

for i := 1 to Count (arr) do
(
    arr[i] := Mid(arr[i],4,5) + ":" + Mid(arr[i],6,7);
)
```

I know this is a very old topic, but because the code helped me I want to post this solution. I had to make some minor adjustments to make it work. Just in case someone else stumbles upon this topic like I did.